# accessing array's last element when passing array in function argument shows garbage value

Tags: c, arrays, function, argument-passing, garbage

I'm passing an array in function argument and when I tried to access the last element using `arr[-1]` in the function's body I'm getting some garbage. Can someone explain me why is that so?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int binsearch(int nelement, int arr[],int maxsize)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = maxsize;

    printf("%d",arr[-1]);
    return 0;       
}

void main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int flag = 3;
    printf("%d\n",arr[8]);
    flag = binsearch(flag,arr,sizeof(arr));
}
```

And here is the output:

```
9
-858993460
```

Comment: Negative indicies are already discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/negative-array-indexes-in-c

Comment: What's up with that code? You're using namespaces, which is a C++ feature; and using `<stdio.h>`, which is C... You want to do C? Ditch the namespaces.

Comment: Unless this code is for an embedded system, it is not valid and will not compile in standard C nor C++, for several reasons.

Answer (score 3):

`arr[-1]` does not access the last element. Conceptually, it access the space before the first element, but the behavior is not defined.

To access the last element, use `arr[nelement-1]` or `arr[NumberOfElements-1]`, depending on what you mean by the last element. (Are you considering the array to contain only `nelement` elements, or do you want the last element in the entire allocated array? If the latter, you will need to know the number of elements in the array in order to calculate the index of the last one.)

Comment: actually when I use python we usually do this to access the last element of array and when i read it into my school notes i found the same, that is why i got confused why it is showing me garbage value. Anyways thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: Using `arr[maxsize-1]` will run into undefined behaviour for sure as well, as depending on the size of an `int` `maxsize` is twice or fours or eights times as large as the array carries `int` elements.

Comment: @alk: Fixed; I mistook their `maxsize` for the maximum number of elements, rather than the array’s size in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Array indicies shall be unsigned. Using a negative value as index to an array provokes undefined behaviour.

---

As a side note:

This code won't pass the number of (`int`) elements down to the function:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
...
flag = binsearch(flag, arr, sizeof(arr));
```

As the `sizeof` operator returns the number of **bytes** used by `arr`.

To pass the number of `int`s the array provides you might like to used the following construct:

```
flag = binsearch(flag, arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **maxsize** is **sizeof(arr)** and arr is an array of **int** - it is the **(sizeof(int) * no_of_elements_of_arr)**

it must be `arr[(maxsize/sizeof(int)) - 1]` in place of `arr[-1]`

`arr[-1]` is expected to print some **garbage** value

Comment: Using `arr[maxsize-1]` will run into undefined behaviour for sure as well, as depending on the size of an `int` `maxsize` is twice or fours or eights times as large as the array carries `int` elements.