# Negative array index

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, access-violation

I have a pointer which is defined as follows:

```
A ***b;
```

What does accessing it as follows do:

```
A** c = b[-1]
```

Is it an access violation because we are using a negative index to an array? Or is it a legal operation similar to `*--b`?

---

**EDIT** Note that negative array indexing has different support in C and C++. Hence, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/are-negative-array-indexes-allowed-in-c) is not a dupe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/negative-array-indexes-in-c

Comment: Congratulations on becoming a three-star programmer.

Comment: It's legal, but not pretty, and potentially undefined behavior until we see what you actually *initialize* `b` to.

Comment: In C++, ordinary pointers (and therefore also arrays) are random access iterators. And random access iterators permit values to be accessed via the offset dereference operator (more commonly known as the subscript or `[]` operator). As others have pointed out, the negative index can be legal. Tricky code like this makes a good learning exercise, but try to avoid it in production code.

Comment: @Dennis: Arrays are not iterators, and they're not pointers either (if that's what you were implying).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is negative index for operator\[\] well defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069280/is-negative-index-for-operator-well-defined)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`X[Y]` is *identical* to `*(X + Y)` as long as one of `X` and `Y` is of pointer type and the other has integral type. So `b[-1]` is the same as `*(b - 1)`, which is an expression that may or may not be evaluated in a well-formed program – it all depends on the initial value of `b`! For example, the following is perfectly fine:

```
int q[24];
int * b = q + 13;

b[-1] = 9;
assert(q[12] == 9);
```

In general, it is *your* responsibility as a programmer to guarantee that pointers have permissible values when you perform operations with them. If you get it wrong, your program has undefined behaviour. For example:

```
int * c = q;   // q as above
c[-1] = 0;     // undefined behaviour!
```

Finally, just to reinforce the original statement, the following is fine, too:

```
std::cout << 2["Good morning"] << 4["Stack"] << 8["Overflow\n"];
```

Comment: I think you should an example that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thumbs up for printing "Ok\n". I didn't know that I can do that!