# Is negative index for operator[] well defined?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

I know it would be very bad coding-style, but the following code runs perfectly on my machine. But is the behavior well defined? Portable?

```
int main()
{
    int *p = new int[3];
    int *q = &p[2];
    q[-1] = 41;
    std::cout << p[1];
    delete[] p;
}
```

Comment: Just an on napkin answer from memory, but I believe that foo[x] is defined in the standard as being exactly equivalent to *(foo + x) where x is an integral type and foo is a pointer so I think it would be legal in any place the later is.

Comment: Don't do this in C++. If I see `thing[-1]` I think "oh, I can read the last element nicely" - like Python, not "it is the thing before whatever this points to"

Comment: @AlecTeal that's really not a good reason to disallow this. If we disallowed every expression that misleadingly resembled a form from another popular language, there would be nothing left. We wouldn't even be able to write IF statement's since they look a lot like Fortan II's arithmetic IF.

Comment: @SteveCox you're right. Programmers of the future will be using this.

Comment: Have you overloaded an operator?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is well defined, both syntactically and semantically.

[expr.sub]/1 (N3337):

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`.

So your expression is the same as `*(q-1) = 41;`, so is syntactically valid.

[expr.add]/5 (N3337)

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression.

Since `q` points to an element of an array object of a valid size for your integral expression, it is semantically valid.

Comment: @immibis I decided to leave that out, as this question is about the validity of the negative index; the indirection is separate, although it's obviously related to the result, which is defined in the second quote. If adding information about the indirection would help the OP I'd be happy to add it, but I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is well defined. Built-in `operator[]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. This:

```
p[N]
```

where `p` is a pointer and `N` is an integer, is equivalent to this:

```
*(p + N)
```

An interesting upshot of this is that this:

```
N[p]
```

is also equivalent, because addition is commutative.

Comment: The latter example assumes the use of the built-in subscript operator.

Comment: @black: So does the former. And I mentioned that at the top of my post.

Comment: Not sure if I'd call it "up"-shot. ;-p Is N[p] ever useful?

Answer (score 7):

According to the C++ Standard (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
>   “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped
>   enumeration or **integral type**. The result is of type “T.” The type
>   “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.65 The expression E1[E2]
>   is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) ...

So you may use any integral type including type `int` and correspondingly negative values provided that the result of expression `*((E1)+(E2))` is well-formed.

Take into account that for user-defined types you may use a brace-init-list as the index. For example

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
public:    
    Point( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x, y;
};

class Circle
{
public:    
    Circle( unsigned int r ) : r( r ) {}

    Circle & operator []( Point p )
    {
        std::cout << "Drawing a circle at ( " << p.x << ", " << p.y << " )\n";
        return *this;
    }

    unsigned int r;
};        

int main()
{
    Circle circle( 10 );

    circle[ { 0, 0 } ];
}
```

The program output is

```
Drawing a circle at ( 0, 0 )
```

Answer (score 3):

The index operator `x[idx]` equals `(*(x +idx))` and yes `idx` might be negative. However, you have to ensure that the dereferenced pointer was pointing to a valid memory address.

Notice that we can rewrite it in many ways (just like algebra).

```
x[idx] = (*(x +idx)) = (*(idx + x)) = idx[x]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely fine so long as you don't attempt to dereference a pointer outside the bounds of the array pointed to by `p`.

Also, you can set the pointer q to any element of the array, and in addition, to one element past the array.  (Don't attempt to dereference an element on past the end of the seat though.)

Don't forget to `delete[] p;` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly safe and portable. You are just using pointer arithmetic to address the memory allocated by the `new` operator.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int* p = new int[3];
int* q = p + 2;
*(q-1) = 41;
```