# Access two dimensional array with negative index in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

i have two dimensional array in C++ like this :

```
int array[2][5] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {6,7,8,9,10}
};
```

when i access the index of array[0][4] , of course the result value will be 5.
But i still confused when i tried access index of array like this array[1][-1],
the result value is 5 too.

Anyone can explain this?
thank you

Comment: You cannot use negative indexes - it is UB. Why are you even trying to do this?

Comment: i just tried for my homework, and it's work i can access negative index with my code, i was compiling the code with dev c++

Comment: Read this. Should answer your question [Negative array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771001/negative-array-index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array index out of bound in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c)

Comment: *i can access negative index with my code* -- And I can drive a car without a driver's license.  Doesn't make it legal though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771001/negative-array-index)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i just ask, because i really really dont know why i can access the value with negative index.

Comment: @NishikinoMaki -- `array[0][-1]` -- Don't be surprised if this "works".  My point is that you can do a lot of things in C++ that are really not legal or what you intended, and things may work, may crash, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how index is calculated, The memory itself is an array of words. when you use two-dimension index [i][j] it is mapped to memory as `i*size2+j` (if array's size was [size1][size2])

so when you calculate this for `[0][4]` and `[1][-1]` you get the same value (0*5+4=4,1*5-1=4)
 [image: two-dimensional array]

Answer (score 2):

It is actually undefined behaviour. The reason why you see 5 is more or less accidental. The reason is that you are creating fixed length two-dimensional array of integers that is created in memory in sequence. Therefore `[1][-1]` is on some (perhaps most?) implementations equivalent to memory location of `[0][4]`. In memory it looks like sequence `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` in your case. But it is not guaranteed or defined that multidimentionsonal fixed-length arrays will be always contiguous like what you observes.

Comment: so [1][-1] is memory address location of [0][4]..
okay thanks