# Array Values in C loops( clang vs gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm-clang

I was trying to play with array initializations in a for loop in c.

Here is the program I tried :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        int br[10]={0};
        printf("%d\n", br[-1]);
    }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

The results of this code when compiled with gcc are:

```
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

The same program when compiled with clang ,the results are:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If I tweak the program  a bit by making a array initialization before starting of second loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    int ar[10]={0};
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        int br[10]={0};
        printf("%d\n", br[-1]);
    }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I get output as `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` for both gcc and clang

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here,when I try to access a negative index why are these results showing up with these two different compilers(gcc and clang) and why is another array initialization before second loop changing everything.

Comment: `br[-1]` is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).... That's all

Comment: I don't think so. I think it has something to do with memory allocations.

Comment: No, it's UB, pure and simple. The compiler reserves the right to eat your cat.

Comment: You are accessing your array out of bounds..... How can't be that UB???

Comment: Yes,I think izlin is correct if I run loop from 5-8 instead of 0-3 output is 5 6 7 5 6 7 5 6 7.Its not undefined behaviour.I think clang does it differently.

Comment: I would say it is unspecified or implementation-defined behaviour because only the values are not defined but br[-1] is!

Comment: @izlin: How do you know br[-1] is defined? If you are thinking in terms of a "stack" then note that a stack is an implementation concept not a language concept.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `br[-1]` is *undefined*.

The C standard does not define the behaviour of attempting to access an element outside the *bounds* of an array. (Interestingly, it's chiefly for this reason why C is regarded as an "unsafe" language by many folk.) You can always inspect the generated assembler for a full analysis of what the compiler has produced.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example of using negative array idexes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/are-negative-array-indexes-allowed-in-c)

If you use br[-1] you print the element before your array:

```
some stuff | your array | more stuff
 X X X X X | 0 0 0 0 ...| X X X X
         ^ this element will be printed
```

So in one case you maybe got the value of i or j, but the number before your array can change with different compilers or compiler options.

@Bathsheba
In my link the top answer says that the behaviour is defined in C99 §6.5.2.1/2, but you don't know which variable is located in front of your array.

> The deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).