# How exactly pointer arithmetic works when add an integer type in C?

Tags: c

In C, given

```
char arr [10];
uint32_t i = -1;
char * p = &arr [1];
```

does (p + i) overflow/undefined or equals to &arr [0]?
why the pointer arithmetic rules in C standard(6.5.6.8) so confusing?

The language defines pointer can do +, -, +=, -= operations with any integer type, what will happen when pointer add a negative int value? What if the representation of the pointer is 4 bytes but the integer operand is int64_t?

The C99 standard defines pointer arithmetic in array index term(6.5.6.8), according to my understanding, it states:

```
char * ptr = …;
char * new_ptr = ptr + int_expr;

assert( (new_ptr - ptr) == (int_expr) );
```

what’s the reason for the obscured, indirect definition?

Comment: Are you sure you want `i` to be `unsigned`? I would not be able to hold negative numbers though.

Comment: What exactly is confusing in the rules?

Comment: Yes it wraps and the value will be much greater than 10 so p+I will refer to memory outside the array. Accessing it is undefined behavior. I can't elaborate more now because of my device. It is not equal to &arr[0]

Comment: Very much related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/are-negative-array-indexes-allowed-in-c

Comment: Thanks very much, I also have the fuzz feeling about it, after reading C99 standard, the new C standard, Pointers on C, the deep C secrets etc, but not found a resource clearly explained it. To make me further confusing, clang -Weverything -std=c99 -pedantic  do NOT produce any warning about the above code. I'm looking for more details.

Comment: @Gerhardh Question updated, thanks

Comment: @alk I just want index to be very large, that's another way of 'uint32_t i = 0xFFFFFFFF'

Comment: @zhaorufei But it is not mandatory for the compiler to prevent undefined behavior (this is almost impossible or would at least produce very defensive code that would lead to very poor performance). Some advanced code verifying tools may analyse such problems, but in general compilers do not. This is the same for integer overflow for example.

Comment: "*obscured, indirect definition*" what do you feel is "*obscured*" and/or "*indirect*"?

Comment: If `a = b + c` then also "usual" arithmetic mandates `a - c == b`.

Comment: "What if the representation of the pointer is 4 bytes but the integer operand is int64_t?" changes nothing. `p + some_big_value` points well outside the range of `char arr [10];` regardless of the _type_ of `some_big_value` or representation of `p`.  This is _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning `-1` to `uint32_t` converts it to `UINT32_MAX` (which is `4294967295`) per [reduced modulo, 6.2.5p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9).

So your code is equivalent to:

```
char arr [10];
uint32_t i = UINT32_MAX;
char * p = &arr [1];
```

`p` points to the second element in the array `arr`. So `p+i`, i.e., `p + 4294967295`, yields a pointer that is certainly not within the array object. So it'd be [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you change the type of `i` to `int32_t` for example, then it can hold the negative value (as you might have intended in the first place).
`p + i`, i.e., `p - 1` would yeild a pointer to the first element in the array `arr` (equivalent to `&arr[0]`). There's no undefined behaviour
because the resulting pointer `p + i` (== `&arr[0]`) is still pointing within the array object and is perfectly valid.

Comment: "`p+i`, i.e., `p + 4294967295`, yields a pointer that is certainly not within the array object." says it all - UB.  Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will overflow and no it won't be equal to &arr[0].

Because the variable `i` is of type `uint32_t` so it actually doesn't have the value `-1` but a very large number `4294967295` which is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary or `0xFFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal.

If you change the type of i to something like `int`  then `i` will then have the value `-1` and `(p+i)` will refer to `arr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Given your example with `i` being an **unsigned** data type, you will definitely point outside of your array `arr` as `-1` is treated as `0xFFFFFFFF`.
But here the confusing part is probably not the pointer arithmetic, but the overflow during type conversion of your index variable.

---

On the other side, using a **signed** data type for `i` you would be on the safe side:

Pointer arithmetic is safe as long as you are within the bounds of one data object. You may also point one element after the last element of an array.

In C it is completely the same whether you write `*(arr+i)` or `arr[i]`.
This means your example

```
char * p = &arr [1];
```

is same as

```
char * p = arr+1;
```

And from this you can derive that `p + (-1)` is equal to `arr+1-1 == arr` and is equal to `&arr[0]` which is perfectly fine pointing within bounds of that array.

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.

This is not confusing, this is just a definition of **pointer arithmetic**. And should be read as:

```
E array[N];
assert( (&array[X]+D) == &array[X+D] );
```

provided that X and X+D are both in [0,N] (you can point one past the last element).

`D` can be any integer expression. In your case it has unsigned integer type (-1 as `uint32_t` is `UINT32_MAX`) so it is undefined behavior as the result is out of the bounds of the array (1+UINT32_MAX>10).

If you had use `int32_t`, the the result would have point to the first element of the array:

```
char array[10];
assert( (&array[1]-1) == &array[0] );
```