# Why are C++ array index values signed and not built around the size_t type (or am I wrong in that)?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, standards, size-t

It's getting harder and harder for me to keep track of the ever-evolving C++ standard but one thing that seems clear to me now is that array index values are meant to be integers (not `long long` or `size_t` or some other seemingly more appropriate choice for a *size*). I've surmised this both from the answer to this question ([Type of array index in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111357/type-of-array-index-in-c)) and also from practices used by well established C++ libraries (like Qt) which also use a simple integer for sizes and array index operators.  The nail in the coffin for me is that I am now getting a plethora of compiler warnings from *MSVC 2017* stating that my `const unsigned long long` (aka `const size_t`) variables are being implicitly converted to type `const int` when used as an array index.

The answer given by Mat in the question linked above quotes the ISO C++ standard draft [**n3290**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n3290.pdf) as saying

> it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

I have no background in reading these specs and precisely interpreting their language, so maybe a few points of clarification:

- Does an *"integral constant expression"* specifically forbid things like `long long` which to me is an integral type, just a larger sized one?
- Does what they're saying specifically forbid a type that is tagged `unsigned` like `size_t`?

If all I am seeing here is true, an array index values are meant to be `signed int` types, why? This seems counter-intuitive to me. The specs even state that the expression *"shall be greater than zero"* so we're wasting a bit if it is `signed`. Sure, we still might want to compare the index with `0` in some way and this is dangerous with `unsigned` types, but there should be cheaper ways to solve that problem that only waste a single value, not an entire bit.

Also, with registers ever widening, a more future-proof solution would be to allow larger types for the index (like `long long`) rather than sticking with `int` which is a problematic type historically anyways (changing its size when processors changed to `32 bits` and then not when they went to `64 bits`).  I even see some people talking about `size_t` anecdotally like it was designed to be a more future-proof type for use with sizes (and not JUST the type returned in service of the `sizeof` operator). But of course, that might be apocryphal.

I just want to make sure my foundational programming understanding here is not flawed. When I see experts like the ISO C++ group doing something, or the engineers of Qt, I give them the benefit of the doubt that they have a good reason! For something like an array index, so fundamental to programming, I feel like I need to know what that reason is or I might be missing something important.

Comment: That quote is about array *size* and not index.

Comment: And while an academic and language-lawyer question like this might be fun, you might be better helped by asking about your specific problem first of all.

Comment: I can't think of a standard library container that doesn't use an unsigned integer  for indexing.

Comment: @user4581301 [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/size)

Comment: Oh and using negative indexes is actually okay! Think about if you have a pointer that is pointing not to the first element, but the *third*, then the index `-1` is valid and will be the previous (and and second) element in the array. Remember that array indexing is nothing more than fancy pointer arithmetic and dereference.

Comment: `span` is more view of a container than a container, but I cede the point.

Comment: Could you share a minimal code sample that shows these errors?  You shouldn't be getting any and you don't using g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39b98bc1a5773cb1

Comment: Related: [Why is size\_t unsigned?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10168079).

Comment: What I am curious about is not the `signed` vs `unsigned` issue, but the size of the index.  In theory, I can create a `std::vector<char>` containing in excess of 2^32 elements on a 64 bit machine.  That is why, for example, `std::vector::size()` returns a `size_type`, not an `unsigned int`.  From this it seems to me that it would make more sense for array and pointer indices to be `ssize_t` rather than `int`

Comment: General pointer arithmetic uses signed `std::ptfdiff_t` as index type. Raw array indexing directly piggybacks on that, which is why it is typically signed. But more specific cases that ask for positive-only indexing (e.g. `std::vector`) prefer unsigned types for indexes.

Comment: "I am now getting a plethora of compiler warnings from MSVC 2017 stating that my const unsigned long long (aka const size_t) variables are being implicitly converted to type const int when used as an array index." Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude All good points!  I don't have a specific problem this is causing. It's just creating a bunch of warnings on some compilers about implicit type casts, mismatched sign types, and loss of precision (all of which have always seemed safe to ignore). It really is just an academic question (I am an academic by trade).

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Thank you for that link! A very helpful point of view there.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude you are right!  that quote is about declarations, not expressions that are accessing the array. So I guess there is no restriction that the result of a subscript expression be greater than zero.  Looks like I should have focused on the second quote from that cited answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm going to try and get to the bottom of those warnings.  They were being displayed in the Qt Creator IDE and when I compiled with Qt Creator. I'm wondering if it was somehow not configured correctly when it is doing in-line linting/code checking.  I will try to post a minimal example that reproduces those warnings in as general a situation as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [[expr.sub]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.sub#1) we have

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other **shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type**. The result is of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.67 The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)), except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise. The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, the index of the subscript operator need to be a unscoped enumeration or integral type.  Looking in [[basic.fundamental]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental) we see that standard integer types are `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`, and their unsigned counterparts.

So any of the standard integer types will work and any other integer type, like `size_t`, will be valid types to use as an array index.  The supplied value to the subscript operator can even have a negative value, so long as that value would access a valid element.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the standard library API prefers that indexes be unsigned type. If you look at the documentation for [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) it notes

> When indexing C++ containers, such as `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc, the appropriate type is the member typedef `size_type` provided by such containers. It is usually defined as a synonym for `std::size_t`.

This is reinforced when looking at signatures for functions such as [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

```
reference       at( size_type pos );
const_reference at( size_type pos ) const;
```

Comment: `std::span::size` returns a signed type :(

Comment: IIRC it's been acknowledged (by some on the standards committee) as a mistake to have size types unsigned due to the many potential pitfalls when mixing signed and unsigned types.  Looking for the reference for this ...

Comment: IIRC follow up: https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/issues/182  not the link is was trying to remember but does contain some informed argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing two types:

1. The first type is the type of object/value that can be use to define the size of an array. Unfortunately, the question that you link to uses *index* where they should have used *array size*. This must be an expression that must be evaluated at compile time and its value must be greater than zero.

   ```
   int array[SomeExpression]; // Valid as long as SomeExpression can be evaluated 
                              // at compile time and the value is greater than zero.
   ```
2. The second type is the type of object/value that can be used to access an array. Given the above `array`,

   ```
   array[i] = SomeValue; // i is an index to access the array
   ```

   `i` does not need to be evaluated at compile time, `i` must be in the range [0, SomeExpression-1]. However it is possible to use negative values as the index to access an array. Since `array[i]` is evaluated as `*(array+i)` (ignoring for the time being the overloaded `operator[]` functions), `i` can be a negative value if `array` happens to point to the middle of an array. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389816/pointer-subscript-starts-from-negative-value/51390295#51390295) to another SO post has more information on the subject.

   Just as an aside, since `array[i]` is evaluated as `*(array+i)`, it is legal to use `i[array]` and is the same as `array[i]`.