# c - pointer arithmetic, unexpected results

Tags: c

Here is an example code:

```
int* arr = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));

arr = arr + 1;
*arr = 11;
arr[-1] = 22;

int x = arr[0]; // x = 11
int y = arr[1]; // y = 194759710
```

After a memory allocation `arr` pointer is incremented. I have expected to get the following results:

```
x == 22
y == 11
```

Could you explain how it works ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are negative array indexes allowed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/are-negative-array-indexes-allowed-in-c)

Comment: @MortenJensen It's not the problem in this case, it's a simple array out of bounds bug hidden by obfuscated code.

Comment: What value did you expect for `y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `x` and `y`, you forgot that `arr` no longer points on allocated memory.

This code do what you want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int* arr = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    int *original = arr;

    arr = arr + 1;

    *arr = 11;
    arr[-1] = 22;

    int x = original [0]; // x = arr[-1]
    int y = original [1]; // y = arr[0]

    printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: BTW: `int* arr = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int))` should be `int* arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int))`. The `(int*)` cast is not wrong but it's useless.

Answer (score 5):

The `y` assignment is incorrect. You only have 2 allocated items so you cannot first increment the pointer by one, then de-reference that pointer with `[1]`, because that gives a 3rd element which doesn't exist.